# Getting jQuery dropdown to display on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a piece of jQuery that I did not write that I am using to power dropdown menus on my website. The code works great but unfortunately the dropdown menu only displays on click and I would like the option for it to also display on hover. Is there any easy way to go about doing this with my existing code?

Here is a live example: **http://jsfiddle.net/up6p5/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    Dropdown

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Profile</li>
        <li>Settings</li>
        <li>Log Off</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 99999;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu { list-style-type: none; }

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:hover { background-color: #f3f8f8; }

.dropdown.dropdown-active .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        // Toggle .dropdown-active on click
        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('dropdown-active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    var dd = new DropDown($('.dropdown'));

    $(document).click(function () {

        // Remove class from all dropdowns
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown-active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/kVBLf/

```
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function () {
    var obj = this;
    $(".dropdown").hover(function (event) {
  $(this).toggleClass("dropdown-active");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
}
```

I've used `.hover(function(event) {...}` so that I can listen the events on the class **dropdown**, then I toggled **dropdown-active** class.

**Edit #1**: See new fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/U8nVH/

```
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function () {
    var obj = this;
    $(this).hide();
    $(".dropdown").hover(function (event) {
      $(this).addClass("dropdown-active");
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    $(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function (event) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
   }
 }
```

First I've changed `.toggleClass` to `.addClass` and if I would say `.removeClass` when `.mouseleave` on the `dropdown` element it would keep the same behaviour and wouldn't keep the submenu stay still. So, I've listened `.mouseleave` event on the (submenu) `.dropdown-menu` and hided when mouse leaves.

**Edit #3**: Okay, so last and the successful version is just like this,

```
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function () {
    var obj = this;

    $(".dropdown").mouseenter(function (event) {
        $(this).addClass("dropdown-active");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-active");
    });   
  }
}
```

So we listened the `.mouseenter`event and added a class of `.dropdown-active` and removed that class when `.mouseleave` .
FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/U8nVH/1/

Comment: This works perfectly but whenever I hover over the "Dropdown" text I cannot move down to the dropdown menu without it hiding. It makes showing/hiding the dropdown menu a little funky, is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Here, check this http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/U8nVH/ I'm editing the answer also.

Comment: It works great but when I move my mouse away from the `.dropdown-menu` class and it hides, it does not show back up when I hover over the Dropdown text again.

Comment: Also, thank you so much for working with me on this, I really appreciate you taking time to help me :)

Comment: You're welcome! I think I solved it, sorry it took some more time than I expected. Here, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/U8nVH/1/ I think the easiest way to achieve will be this one.

Comment: You're welcome :) I was also in need of this hehe. Hope the rest goes well!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        // Toggle .dropdown-active on click
        obj.dd.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (event) {
            $(this).addClass('dropdown-active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up6p5/17/)

Comment: It works a little funky with just 'mouseenter'. Change 'mouseenter' to 'mouseenter mouseleave' to have it close the dropdown when your mouse is no longer on top of the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, this is very, very close. So the dropdown works great when I hover over the "Dropdown" text, but the menu only goes away if I hover over the "Dropdown" text again. Could you possibly make the menu go away if I just hover over anything *but* the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

Add this mouseover handler to your init event function.

```
    obj.dd.on('click mouseover', function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('dropdown-active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like ;

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        // Toggle .dropdown-active on click
        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('dropdown-active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        obj.dd.hover ( function (event) {
            if (event.type == "mouseenter") {
                $(this).addClass('dropdown-active');
            }
            else { // mouseleave
                 $(this).removeClass('dropdown-active');
            }
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    var dd = new DropDown($('.dropdown'));


});
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/up6p5/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace " click " to "hover"  here:
// Toggle .dropdown-active on click
        obj.dd.on('hover', function (event)

Your code is absolutely fine and work properly.